# Meaning of "make" in "Can you make me a copy of this?"

Tags: grammar, verbs, expressions, idiomatic-language

I found it's spoken quite commonly but if I'm a speaker, I'd rather try to say something like "can you make a copy of this for me", that is using "for me". The original sentence looks like it's having "me" as a direct object. How is this correct and what grammar is applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you make me a copy of this?

> Can you make a copy of this for me?

Both forms are fine and are similar.

These two sentences have the respective constructions:

> a.  modal verb + S + V + NP Dative + NP

> b.  modal verb + S + V + NP + PP Dative

The noun phrases are the direct objects of their respective verbs.  The indirect objects are either in the NP form, like *NP Dative*, or embedded in prepositional phrases, like *PP Dative*.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_shift) explains **dative shift**.

> [D]ative shift refers to a pattern in which the subcategorization of a verb can take on two alternating forms, the oblique dative form or the double object construction form.  In the oblique dative (OD) form, the verb takes a noun phrase (NP) and a dative prepositional phrase (PP)....

> (1) John gave [NP a book ] [PP.DATIVE to Mary ].

> In the double object construction (DOC) form the verb takes two noun phrases...with the dative argument preceding the other argument.

> (2) John gave [NP.DATIVE Mary ] [NP a book ].

In the title, you have asked for the meaning of *make*.  *make* means produce as in 'produce a copy of this'.

Edit

Not all transitive verbs accept indirect objects.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb) explains *monotransitive* and *ditransitive* verbs.

> Transitive verbs can be classified by the number of objects they require. Verbs that accept only two arguments, a subject and a single direct object, are monotransitive. Verbs that accept two objects, a direct object and an indirect object, are ditransitive.

More explanation on transitivity and examples on use of monotransitive verbs, among others, are found [here](https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/914283#:%7E:text=A%20monotransitive%20verb%20is%20a,eat%20are%20monotransitive%20in%20English.).

> The cat bit me!

> He broke the toothpick.

Comment: Thanks. But can I use datives with any transitive verbs? I frequently heard the verbs like "provide" or "give" having indirect objects but I'm not sure if I can use them with any other transitive verbs.

Comment: I have added more explanations in my answer.

Comment: I've never heard of 'monotransitive' and 'ditransitive' verbs. Many thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

"Me", in your example, is the [indirect object](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/indirect_object.htm). Indirect objects are quite common in formal and in colloquial English. For example,

```
Hand *me* the book.
I gave *her* the money.
Would you please get *me* an ice cream?
```

However, this can lead to puns, such as, ["Make me one with everything."](https://bestcleanfunnyjokes.com/make-me-one-with-everything/)